# Mysql SUM by value in column

Tags: mysql

I have problem to get the proper result. 
I have a table with registered time entries by date and user.
I also have a date table, that only consists of dates.

```
CREATE TABLE `jobbile_job_record` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `note` text,
  `time_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobbile_job_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inserted` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `time_registered` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1145 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

I would like to get a result of
- date
- total time registered
- total time by user (registered)

I use the following query:

```
SELECT
date.date,
SUM(jobbile_job_record.time_registered) as 'total time',
SUM(jobbile_job_record.time_registered AND `jobbile_job_record`.`created_by` = '5713') as 'User 5713',
SUM(jobbile_job_record.time_registered AND `jobbile_job_record`.`created_by` = '5714') as 'User 5714'
FROM
date
LEFT JOIN jobbile_job_record
ON date.date = jobbile_job_record.created
WHERE
date.date BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-11-30'
GROUP BY
date.date
ORDER BY
date.date ASC
```

Total_time works fine but the two SUM's with users filtered, is not summarized but counted.
Cant I use this method? Thanks!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ``SUM(jobbile_job_record.time_registered AND `jobbile_job_record`.`created_by` = '5713')`` is the sum of a boolean value (0 or 1) because of the `AND` keyword. That's why you get a result like a count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need a case statement here -

```
SELECT
date.date,
SUM(jobbile_job_record.time_registered) as 'total time',
SUM(CASE WHEN `jobbile_job_record`.`created_by` = '5713' THEN jobbile_job_record.time_registered END) as 'User 5713',
SUM(CASE WHEN `jobbile_job_record`.`created_by` = '5714' THEN jobbile_job_record.time_registered END ) as 'User 5714'
FROM date
LEFT JOIN jobbile_job_record ON date.date = jobbile_job_record.created
WHERE date.date BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-11-30'
GROUP BY date.date
ORDER BY date.date ASC
```